# How can I get backup the files from my semi-broken android before shipping it in?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, backup, data-recovery

I broke my Samsung Galaxy SIII (Red) last week, got a replacement in the mail, and I'm trying to back up my files (contacts, photos, etc.) onto my computer before I send the broken one in. The only problem is that when I plug it in it doesn't show up anywhere as a device. On my old Samsung it used to be that I would have to go to USB options in my phone before it showed up as a device, but being unable to do that now is my main problem. Is there any way around this? I went to my provider's store and they said they wouldn't do it for some reason or other. Also, I tried backing up my contacts at least through Gmail, but apparently that didn't work either.

Comment: Which Android version? Custom or stock recovery? And yes, you'd need to enable *USB Debugging* for the device itself being recognized (and not just the "drive" with the "shared storage", which doesn't help for this issue). You might want to check the [best questions tagged data-recovery](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery?sort=frequent&pagesize=15), especially [How do I backup data (SMS/contacts) from a device with a broken screen?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25646/16575)