# Restore SMS from a phone with broken screen

Tags: sms, data-recovery

I have a *Samsung Galaxy S* phone with a broken screen. I have text messages on it from about 2 years ago (which I need for court).

After the screen broke I changed service providers. Now their is no service to the phone. So if I fix the phone will my messages still be on the phone?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [How do I backup data (SMS/contacts) from a device with a broken screen?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25646/16575) -- as you main issue is probably exactly that. Once you've restored them, you most likely will not care if a screen replacement would wipe them from the device :)

Answer (score 0):

The SMS will still be there, assuming that:

- you have not wiped, or done a Factory Reset on the phone
- the SMS was saved to the Phone and not the SIM
- the phone can still be repaired