# Is there anyway to save my contacts and texts on a Samsung Galaxy Nexus with broken screen?

Tags: contacts, sms, root-access, backup, broken-screen

Broke my screen, and it's dead. I searched the forums, and I could not find an answer. I don't care about my media files, but my contacts are really important to me. I already ordered the new Nexus 5, but I need those contacts.

I tried Holo Backup, and it doesn't work. Any Ideas?

Comment: @DanHulme No, I turned on USB debugging.

Comment: Also see: [How do I backup data (SMS/contacts) from a device with a broken screen?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25646/16575)

Answer (score 0):

I'm missing some information:

- Is your phone rooted?
- Do you have USB debugging enabled?
- Are your contacts synced to your Google account?

Since it isn't clear from the question - have you checked that your contacts aren't already backed up to your Google account? If you had your contacts synced - then they should all be backed up to the cloud / your connected Google account.

If that's not the case, and all you need is to be able to see your screen and control your phone (via the app of your choice) - you can try [this kind of solution](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/119069-how-to-use-the-galaxy-nexus-as-a-desktop-replacement) - an an MHL-enabled USB port.

Also, maybe [Airdroid](http://www.airdroid.com/), can help as well.

Answer (score -2):

My brother had a Samsung galaxy S-4, and he started having minor issues with it so he brought it into the store. the end result was him walking out with an S-5, and he explained to me a galaxy-specific process that allowed him to put everything into the new phone. his contacts, wallpapers, music and everything else. i assume that he started the process on the older phone, and this might not be helpful to you, but that's all i know and hopefully this is helpful to you somehow. wish i could do more, that's awful.

Comment: i can barely beleive how useless this answer is. but i figure it's better to say something than nothing at all.