# How to get text messages off phone with broken screen

Tags: sms, 4.1-jelly-bean, usb-debugging, broken-screen

I would like to access and transfer text messages from an Xperia E to a new phone. I've found several applications that appear to let me do so, but all of them require USB Debugging to be on. Since the screen is broken (but I do still have touch functionality as far as I can tell) I have no idea how to turn this feature on.

All questions about the USB debugging issue get closed and redirected to an existing question that doesn't help me, so I'm hoping that there is some way to get the texts without the need for USB debugging.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Have you seen our [broken-screen tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info) – and especially [How do I backup data (SMS/contacts) from a device with a broken screen?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25646/16575) (hint: most of our tags have tag-wikis holding first-aid and links to important questions/answers ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you still have touch functionality, you may be able to export the texts right from the app. (If your texting app has that functionality.)

In terms of USB debugging, if you are not seeing the "Developer Options" choice, you may need to go to settings > about phone, then find "Build Number" and tap it multiple times, until it says you are a developer.

If you really can't get USB debugging on, I would recommend [Avast Mobile Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.avast.android.backup&hl=en), it will backup my SMS messages without USB debugging.

Hope this helps and good luck.