# Is it possible to read SMS with broken touch and disabled usb debug?

Tags: sms, broken-screen

I've just broken my touch screen, but there is an extremely important text message in my device. USB debug is disabled, and I can't enable it because touch is broken. :\
Is it possible to reach that SMS somehow? Could it be reachable via Google services somehow? The device is functional and is connected to internet.

Comment: You might wish to check: [How do I backup data (SMS/contacts) from a device with a broken screen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/25646/16575)

Answer (score 1):

If your device has a USB OTG port (My Xperia Z1 Compact and Nexus 7 do, and I believe most recent devices do) you may be in luck - get a USB OTG adapter (mine was from a pound shop - if your in the uk try Poundland) and a USB mouse - plug them in to your phone and you can then control it.

Its a bit of a faff at first but better than nothing.

Comment: And I always seems to forget that mouse and keyboard can easily be connected in Android like with any other Linux system. :-)

Comment: Yupp. And if the device has an HDMI port, a matching cable and TV might solve the issue with "visibility" – if the device is lacking that as well :)