# Broken, unresponsive screen: how to recover data on this otherwise working phone?

Tags: data-recovery, file-transfer, broken-screen, huawei-ascend-p7

today my Huawei Ascend P7 has met its sad end, falling 2 meters to its screen-death. The phone still rings, turns on and off, and the volume buttons still work, but the screen doesn't work at all. It will not let me transfer data without accepting the connection in the phone, so I can't just go in with Android File Transfer. I have found guides for Samsung phones and Motorola phones, but I can't find one that will work with my Chinese Hauwei phone.

I do have Google Play activated and it lets me remotely install apps, if that helps.

> Is there a generic method of recovering data from the phone with a broken screen?

---

Other notes: I my phone should have Android 4.4. It does not have an SD card, but I can find one if that would help. It does not have any special settings on, just standard Android.

Comment: I considered buying a new screen, but it is ~40 dollars in parts and looks as hard as replacing an iPhone screen. I think I'd rather just get a used phone, since I can get a used G2 for 100 dollars.

Comment: Also, I do not know if this applies to me, I do not have Samsung:
http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25646/how-do-i-backup-data-sms-contacts-from-a-device-with-a-broken-screen?rq=1

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! As you've already picked the right tag, have you checked our [broken-screen tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info) – which contains some first aid and links? Indeed it even has a section on data recovery, which might help you.

Comment: @Izzy Hello and thank you for your comment, I will try checking that out later when I have more time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would try plugging the phone into your computer with a USB cable and copying all the files you can to your computer.  Then transfer the files to your new phone.

Comment: I can't do that because my phone will not connect to my computer unless I grant the computer permission from within the phone