# How to backup contacts to Google from Samsung devices which don't export vcf file?

Tags: contacts, google-contacts, google-backup

The Contact apps that ships with Samsung devices does not seem to have a function to reliably backup *all* contacts on the phone and SIM storage to Google accounts.

Is there any third-party app that'd let me reliably do so? Bonus points if it'd let me sort which contact goes to which Google accounts registered on the device.

As a last resort, if there's no such app, I don't mind if I can get to backup to storage with which I can transfer the contacts to a different device.

**PS** I intentionally point to a specific model because I need to do so from two different Samsung devices and both their contact apps did not let me move all contacts to Google account. One of them does have `.vcf` export, but the other doesn't. I want a more universal solution if at all possible.

**PPS** The device that can do `.vcf` export has Google accounts correctly setup on both the new and old devices but all contacts has not been synced, hence the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the contacts backup apps lack one feature or the other e.g. they don't backup high resolution photo when creating `.vcf` file. So I prefer CLI method to extract contacts data directly from database file using some scripting, but ***it requires root***. That's how I do scheduled back up of my contacts without Google account.

The following script doesn't save Google sync account information to `.vcf` file but you can extend the script to include/exclude any data if the concept is perceived.

Original credits to [dump-contacts2db.sh](https://github.com/stachre/dump-contacts2db).

```
#!/system/bin/bash -e

# dumps following fields of contacts from Android's sqlite database to vcf:
# Name, Phone Number, Email, Address, Photo, Title, Organization, Notes, Website
# required binaries: sqlite3, base64, xxd (all included with Android)

# contacts directory, database file and photos directory
CONT_PROVIDER='/data/user/0/com.android.providers.contacts'
DB="$CONT_PROVIDER/databases/contacts2.db"
PHOTO_DIR="$CONT_PROVIDER/files/photos"

# vcf file
VCF="/data/media/0/contacts_$(date '+%d-%b-%y_%H-%M-%S').vcf"

# delete backup file if error occurs
trap '[ $? -eq 0 ] || rm -f $VCF' EXIT

GEN_VCARD()
{
    # skip blank contact for first time
    [ -n "$name" ] || return 0

    # count number of contacts
    n=$((n+1))

    vcard="${name}${tel}${adr}${email}${url}${note}${org}${title}${photo}"
    vcard="BEGIN:VCARD"$'\n'"VERSION:3.0"$'\n'"${vcard}""END:VCARD"
    echo "$vcard" >>$VCF
    echo >>$VCF
}

# fetch contacts data from different columns of 'view_entities' table of contacts sqlite database
ROWS="$(
sqlite3 $DB "
SELECT
    view_entities._id, view_entities.mimetype_id, view_entities.data1, view_entities.data2, view_entities.data3,
    view_entities.data4, view_entities.data5, view_entities.data6, quote(view_entities.data15), view_entities.photo_uri
FROM view_entities
WHERE view_entities.deleted = 0
ORDER BY view_entities._id, view_entities.mimetype_id
")"

# to parse rows
IFS=$'\n'

# iterate through contacts data rows
for ROW in $ROWS
do
    # to parse columns from a row
    IFS="|"
    i=0

    # iterate through columns
    for COL in $ROW
    do
        i=$((i+1))

        # data included in each column
        case $i in
            1)  # Contact ID
                id=$COL;;

            2)  # Mime Type ID
                mime_id=$COL;;

            3)  # Phone Number, Website, Email, Notes, Address, Organization
                data=$COL;;

            4)  # Type ID of Phone No. / Email / Address, First Name
                first_name=$COL; type_id=$COL;;

            5)  # Name of Custom Phone No. Type / Email Type / Address Type, Last Name
                last_name=$COL; type=$COL;;

            6)  # Name Prefix, Title
                name_prefix=$COL; tytle=$COL;;

            7)  # Middle Name
                middle_name=$COL;;

            8)  # Name Suffix
                name_suffix=$COL;;

            9)  # Photo thumbnail hex data
                photo_hex=$COL;;

            10) # Full resolution Photo URI
                photo_uri=$COL;;
        esac
    done

    # start new contact when all rows of same contact ID are parsed
    if [ "$prev_id" != "$id" ]
    then
        # echo current vcard prior to resetting variables
        GEN_VCARD

        # init new vcard
        for i in name tel adr email url note photo org title; do eval "$i=''"; done
    fi

    # add current row to current vcard, 'mimetype' determines data type on every row
    case $mime_id in
        1)
            # Email
            case $type_id in
                0)  email_type=X-$type;;
                1)  email_type=HOME;;
                2)  email_type=WORK;;
                3)  email_type="";;
                4)  email_type=CELL;;
                *)  echo "Unknown email type of '$data'" >&2; exit 1;;
            esac

            email=$email'EMAIL;TYPE='$email_type':'$data$'\n';;

        4)
            # Organization, Title
            org='ORG:'$data$'\n'
            title='TITLE:'$tytle$'\n';;
        5)
            # Phone No.
            case $type_id in
                0)  tel_type=X-$type;;
                1)  tel_type=HOME;;
                2)  tel_type=CELL;;
                3)  tel_type=WORK;;
                7)  tel_type=VOICE;;
                12) tel_type=PREF;;
                *)  echo "Unknown phone no. type of '$data'" >&2; exit 1;;
            esac

            tel=$tel'TEL;TYPE='$tel_type':'$data$'\n';;

        7)
            # Name
            name="$name_prefix $first_name $middle_name $last_name $name_suffix"

            # remove leading/trailing spaces
            IFS=' ' read name <<<"$name"

            # always add complete name as First Name
            name="N:;"$name";;;"$'\n'"FN:"$name$'\n';;
        8)
            # Postal Address
            case $type_id in
                0)  adr_type=X-$type;;
                1)  adr_type=HOME;;
                2)  adr_type=WORK;;
                *)  echo "Unknown address type of '$data'" >&2; exit 1;;
            esac

            adr=$adr'ADR;TYPE='$adr_type':;;'$data';;;;'$'\n';;

        10)
            # Photo
            if [ $photo_hex != "NULL" ]
            then
                # look for high-resolution photo instead of thumbnail
                uri=$(echo $photo_uri | sed 's|content://com.android.contacts/display_photo|'"$PHOTO_DIR"'|')
                if [ -f $uri ]
                then
                    # convert binary to base64
                    foto="$(base64 -w 0 $uri)"
                else
                    # remove prefix/suffix from hex output, convert hex to binary to base64
                    foto=$(echo $photo_hex | sed "s/^X'//; s/'$//" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | xxd -pr | base64 -w 0)
                fi

                photo="PHOTO;ENCODING=BASE64;JPEG:"$foto$'\n'
            fi;;

        12)
            # Note
            note="NOTE:"$data$'\n';;

        14)
            # Website
            url=$url"URL:"$data$'\n';;

        *)  echo "Unknown mime type: '$(sqlite3 $DB "SELECT view_entities.mimetype FROM view_entities WHERE view_entities.mimetype_id = $mime_id" | head -n1)'" >&2; exit 1;;

    esac

    # preserve current ID to compare with next row
    prev_id=$id

    # reset IFS for parent loop to parse rows
    IFS=$'\n'
done

# echo last vcard, loop is done
GEN_VCARD

echo "Backed up $n contacts."
```

If you prefer GUI or don't have root, you can use some app like [Contacts VCF](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=by.androld.contactsvcf).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did when I need to have a backup of my contacts. Because I lost most of them in a factory reset. But some contacts were there in my gmail account and sim card. So I did,

1. I copy all the contacts to the gmail account I have connected.(copied to 2 accounts)
2. Using google contacts app I remove duplicated and empty contacts.
3. I have selected my gmail account as the default contact saving place (not the phone or sim card. Its directly save to the google)

Now I can use google contacts app on any device or just contacts.google.com using any web browser on pc or mobile to access my contacts anywhere anytime.