# How to export contacts from the command line in standard format?

Tags: applications, contacts

If a phone gets itself into a bad state and starts rebooting for no good reason, is there a way to export the contacts info so that after the phone is restored, the contacts can be reinstated? I don't think they were stored to the SIM.

Comment: Do you use Google Play Store on your phone? If yes you are logged in with Google and contacts should be synced to Google Contacts. Check it out: https://contacts.google.com SIM contacts are nowadays used only by a few people, mainly because each entry only supports one name + one phone number.

Comment: No, I don't. The phone is in a boot loop so I can only log in via adb.

Comment: On modern devices adb backup does not include contacts, see [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/85269/2241). Therefore only if your device is rooted you may be able to extract the contacts.

Comment: It would not be easy to export in standard format (do you mean a vcard/vcf?). You would want to try this answer first to verify whether adb can indeed access your contacts data or not. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59107487

Comment: Here is a shell script I use sometimes to export contacts from `contacts2.db` to VCF using `sqlite3` commandline tool: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215426/218526