# backup on Linux desktop of an android phone

Tags: backup, linux

I am fluent with Linux command line (using Linux since 1993). I have a Ubuntu 21.10 desktop (with root access, and good fiber-optic connection to the internet).

My mobile phone is a Redmi Note 7 (M1901F7G) with an extra µsim SD Card. Android 1QKQ1.190910.002. `lsusb` on the desktop says:

```
 Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2717:ff40 Xiaomi Inc. Mi/Redmi series (MTP)
```

with other output.

I have connected the phone to the desktop with an USB cable.

I want to backup all the phone contacts (first & last name & phone number) on the desktop, reset the mobile phone entirely, and transfer the saved up contacts back. Preferably by typing Linux commands on the desktop (e.g. `mtp-getfile` ?)

I don't mind losing Android applications on the mobile phone. I would be upset in losing the human contact (adress book).

I also have a wifi

I don't have Windows, and never used it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exporting contacts via adb](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/176172/exporting-contacts-via-adb)

Comment: MTP protocol is not recommended, consider [adb-sync](https://github.com/google/adb-sync) for file transfer and [adb backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28296) for apps. regarding contacts find software for your needs. [MyPhoneExplorer](https://www.fjsoft.at/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7617) afaik runs from wine

Comment: for most distros package should be available `android-tools-adb`

Comment: Oh why they blocked you? stackoverflow admins are so stupid cannot differentiate between spammer or good people!? My sincere condolences for the discrimination