# What is the path where GoSMS stores the SMS messages

Tags: sms, file-system, go-sms

How say the title I can't find where the sms are stored.
I see this [similar question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16915/where-on-the-file-system-are-sms-messages-stored) but the replies haven't helped me.

I have gosms and I want delete all messages, but if I do this option with gosms the app crashes because are a lot of messages (about 6000).

I found:

```
./data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/mmssms.db
./data/data/com.jb.gosms/databases/gommssms.db
```

But are too small files (a few kb) and with text reader I saw that they contained only some queries. Also when I deleted them if I open gosms I still see all messages. So what is the real path of sms?

Edit:
After a reboot gosms can't find sms anymore, so my problem is solved (
though probably the real sms are still stored somewhere)

Comment: Looks like the correct ones to me. "a few kb" does also make sense, considered that a SMS can have max 160 chars. Maybe you could [edit] your question and add how exactly you deleted what from where? I don't think you simply deleted those databases. But using SQL's `DELETE` command, you might e.g. have missed the `COMMIT` to make your `DELETE`s persistent, and thus your changes might have been "rolled back" instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where on the file system are SMS messages stored?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16915/where-on-the-file-system-are-sms-messages-stored)

Comment: This could just be a comment to, and a continuation of the accepted answer to the previous question.

Comment: @Izzy I deleted the databases using a file explorer (rootexplorer) and I clicked on the button to delete the databases from filesystem

Comment: @wbogacz Mmm.. I hadn't considered this possibility

Comment: What about a reboot? It could have taken them from cache. Btw: Not a very clever idea to delete the database file, as this way settings could get lost as well. Though the app should re-create the database file as if it had just been installed, it might also crash if not considering this (finding its other files intact, it might not think it has to re-create anything).

Comment: Yes, I know the risks of my actions, but finally with a reboot all seems ok :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMS messages are stored in `data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db`. If you can't see it in your root explorer (or it is to small), try rebooting your device or simply - connect your phone to the computer and copy that file (using e.g. ADB) on it and I'm sure you will be able to read it properly .