# Android SMS path

Tags: sms

I can't find the path of SMS database files in android os.
where is the right path for SMS database files?

I already tried these values and these values are not right:

```
/data/data/com.jb.gosms/databases/gommssms.db
/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db
```

Comment: It works : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162129/android-sms-path/20162464?noredirect=1#20162464

Comment: And a quick [on-site search for "databases/gommssms.db"](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=databases%2Fgommssms.db) reveals: [Where on the file system are SMS messages stored?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/16915/16575) / [What is the path where GoSMS stores the SMS messages](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/55746/16575) :)