# wiped SD card, trying to find text messages

Tags: sms, sd-card, data-recovery

A friend borrowed my microSD card to take some pictures and ended up deleting the android directories.  I assumed that text messages were stored on this card.  No message history appeared after the card was removed.  incoming messages from old contacts started new threads.  contacts and everything else stayed.

I want to find the year's worth of old text messages.

I've recovered some files using photorec (mostly pictures and audio from my phone).  The only non-obvious files are a 10MB .elf file and a 72KB .SQLITE file.  the directory structure is not preserved, so all files appear in one directory.

does this approach make sense?
what file extension am I looking for? 
how do I read the database that texts are stored in?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where on the file system are SMS messages stored?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16915/where-on-the-file-system-are-sms-messages-stored)

Comment: In a sense. They are usually *not* stored on your SDCard – unless you did some tricky things with DirectoryBind, Link2SD, and the like. Did you?

Comment: Try to examine the `.sqlite` file. It could be the database containing the SMS, although that's not typical as @Izzy already mentioned.

Comment: It would also help to know the complete name of the `.sqlite` file to determine whether it's really related (which I massively doubt). The `.elf` file you can ignore, that's a so-called [ELF binary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELF_binary), and doesn't hold any of your personal data.