# How to copy SMS messages from phone to PC if I can't install apps?

Tags: sms, backup

I want to back up the SMS messages on my phone (an Alcatel One Touch Evolve 2), and I guess the simplest way to do that is to copy the SMS database to my PC.

According to [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/54758), the SMS database is found at:

```
/data/data/com.android.providers/telephony/databases/mmssms.db
```

However, this database seems to only be user-accessible if the phone is rooted, and I am currently unable to install any apps on this phone.  Every time I try to install an app from the Google Play store, I get a message saying that there is "Insufficient storage", even if I just uninstalled the same app and am trying to reinstall it.  This is probably a memory issue that requires a factory reset, which is why I'm trying to back up my SMS data before resetting the phone, but how can I get to the database if I can't put an app on the phone to root it?

Comment: Delete some of the apps or apps' data to gain some space. After that you can install [Helium](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup&hl=en) or any SMS backup app from Play Store. They don't need root access. However, no matter whether you do reset or not the storage issue will haunt you again. Also see Q/A in [tag:insufficient-memory] tag.

Comment: … and make sure to check the [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info), which gives you some first aid on solving that underlying issue.

Comment: @Firelord, I haven't been able to get Helium to work because my laptop won't recognize my phone, see [this post](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/124307/windows-wont-recognize-my-phone-tried-universal-adb-driver).

Comment: sigil, always attempt to use alternatives. Didn't I say "any SMS backup app from Play Store"? You need not to remain stuck and troubleshooting the Helium or ADB. Use [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore&hl=en) to backup the SMS'/MMS' in any folder you want and then move them to PC simply.

Comment: @Firelord, I can't install any apps on my phone.  I have 132 MB free on internal storage, and I've cleared cache for all apps, but I'm still getting the "Insufficient Storage" message whenever I try to install anything from the Play Store.  I think a factory reset will fix this, so that's why I'm trying to back up all my SMS first.

Comment: Remove some of the apps as I said earlier. Do not proceed for cache but uninstall the apps.

Answer (score -2):

Use [Alcatel PC Suite](http://alcatelonetouch.com/global-en/support/download/ot-710.html). You can synchronize your smartphone data with PC this way.

Comment: Link for the software please? Also, how to use this software to achieve what you wrote in answer? Please detail.

Comment: Tried this, but because my PC doesn't recognize my phone, even with the Universal ADB Driver, I can't use it.