# "com.android.phone has stopped" after dirty flashing CM13

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, custom-roms, force-close

After dirty flashing my OnePlus One (bacon) from CM12.1 to CM13, I am constantly getting force close dialogs popup

```
Unfortunately the process com.android.phone has stopped
```

Logcat is filled with stacktraces like this:

```
Shutting down VM
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.android.phone, PID: 13148
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.android.providers.telephony.TelephonyProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5205)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4797)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4737)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1424)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
    at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
    at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
    at com.android.providers.telephony.TelephonyProvider$DatabaseHelper.getStringValueFromCursor(TelephonyProvider.java:993)
    at com.android.providers.telephony.TelephonyProvider$DatabaseHelper.copyPreservedApnsToNewTable(TelephonyProvider.java:905)
    at com.android.providers.telephony.TelephonyProvider$DatabaseHelper.onUpgrade(TelephonyProvider.java:641)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:256)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
    at com.android.providers.telephony.TelephonyProvider.onCreate(TelephonyProvider.java:1457)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1748)
    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1723)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5202)
    ... 10 more
```

Once I somehow get rid of the persistent UI popup, it seems like `com.android.phone` is crashing at least 10 times per second, flooding logcat, and making it almost impossible to use the phone.

Is there any hope for a fix, or is a hard reset the only option?

Comment: Do clear data for `com.android.providers.telephony` (app goes by the label "Phone/Telephony storage/providers"). While you're on it, do it for Phone app as well (`com.android.phone`), restart and tell us the results.  It appears that the database of `com.android.providers.telephony` cannot be read. It may be possible that you can't clear data for those apps. In that case, remove their /data/data directories from the face of earth.

Comment: Clearing the cache (from recovery) may help

Comment: I tried to remove these folders using Total Commander in root mode. I managed to delete but it didn't help. I made a reboot as well :( I can't call anyone...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was because of a change in the code.

As Firelord has said, clear the data for the apps, This can be done like so (**this will also delete your SMS/MMS database, so make sure to backup them beforehand**):

```
adb shell
rm -fr /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/
rm -fr /data/data/com.android.phone/
exit
```

The -f flag is for force and -r flag means recursive.

Comment: That worked! Thanks. I also noticed this line in my logcat: `TelephonyProvider: dbh.onUpgrade:+ db=SQLiteDatabase: /data/user/0/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/telephony.db oldV=1114120 newV=1376264` After removing the data dir and a reboot, the force close dialogs stopped. What was in the database? I noticed all my text messages are gone. Anything else?

Comment: **Readers:** make sure to reboot the device after deleting those directories.

Comment: Interesstingly it was not possible to delete the data from the App menu. I needed to reboot into TWRP and delete the folder there (the first one was sufficient)

Comment: This method doesn't work for Cyanogenmod 14/Android 7

Comment: @Adem Nov , whats the logcat?

Comment: I purged cm14 and reinstalled cm13 because cm14 was too unfinished for me. Everything works fine for me on cm13.

Comment: @Adem databases may have moved http://android.stackexchange.com/a/155895/136434

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem while upgrading to CM13 from CM12.1. You can solve this problem without deleting your database files and therefore losing data as suggested in the other answers.

The culprit seems to be broken database [onUpgrade code](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_providers_TelephonyProvider/blob/1c66f945564d0e61d989eed38d50224460aa320a/src/com/android/providers/telephony/TelephonyProvider.java#L905)  in the TelephonyProvider of CM.
The `ppp_number` column of the carriers table does not exists, but the upgrade code assumes it already exists.

I solved it by copying the telephony.db to my local Linux machine and reverting the database version to version `16 << 16 | 6 = 1048582` to force the upgrade code to add the missing columns. The `ALTER TABLE` statements in the linked code are guarded by try-catch-blocks, so that it doesn't matter if some of the columns already exists. Boot the phone into recovery (e.g. TWRP) to have adb root priviliges and avoid lock races with the Android Runtime which is constantly trying to start the telephony provider.

```
% adb pull /data/user/0/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/telephony.db
% adb pull /data/user/0/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/telephony.db-journal
```

Create backups

```
% cp telephony.db telephony.db.bak
% cp telephony.db-journal telephony.db-journal.bak
```

Then open the database with sqlite and set the version

```
% sqlite3 telephony.db
sqlite> PRAGMA user_version = 1048582;
sqlite> .quit
```

Upload the changed database back to the device and fix permissions

```
% adb push telephony.db /data/user/0/com.android.providers.telephony/databases
% adb shell
~ # cd /data/user/0/com.android.providers.telephony/databases
/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases # rm telephony.db-journal
/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases # chown radio:radio telephony.db
/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases # chmod 660 telephony.db
```

You could also try this on the broken system, which I wouldn't recommend. You would probably have to become root with `adb root` in order to copy and modify the files with `adb`.

Comment: Excellent attention to detail!  The explanation is much appreciated.  Like @gedenkt, I followed these instructions, but they didn't work for me either. :-/  Simply deleting these two `*.db*` files did solve the problem though.

Comment: You can use the "vacuum" command to merge the journal to the db. `$ sqlite3 telephony.db VACUUM`

Answer (score 4):

I tried Sebastian's solution, but the error persisted.
The accepted answer results in losing all your SMS, therefore was not an option for me.
However, after booting into recovery mode and deleting the files

```
/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/telephony.db
/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/telephony.db-journal
```

the phone worked perfectly again. The files seem to contain only auto-generated data, so it is safe to delete them.

Comment: How can I delete certain files in recovery mode?

Comment: @Hinrich If you use a full-featured recovery like TWRP, you can use the built-in file manager.

Comment: Here's a bit more detail on TWRP.  In my case, I'm running Safestrap 3.75 (TWRP v2.7.1.0), and I had to use the "Mount" button, then check "Data," then go back, then use the "Advanced" button to use the "File Manager" button (then navigate, starting from the "data" folder).

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to get in to an adb shell or remove the directory from your phone because it is unusable you can also remove the directory from whitin TWRP recovery.

Comment: Please add the necessary directions to do that in your answer. What if the OP doesn't have TWRP?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same poblem after updating from CM12 to CM13. Here is how I was able to fix it:

I removed these two directories

```
/data/user/0/com.android.providers.telephony
/data/data/com.android.phone/
```

completly from my phone (Nexus 5). I used `ES Explorer` to do so, I had to turn on `Root Mode` and `Show Hidden Files` to be able to delete files in that directory.

Call log and SMS are still there, cannot see any disadvantages resulting from deleting those directories. Everything seems to work smooth again.