# Android 6.0.1 'Message Service' crash on boot - S7 Edge

Tags: sms, 6.0-marshmallow, stock-rom, services, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I recently purchased a Samsung S7 Edge. As I like to play around with my phones a lot, one of the first things I did was root it. Not thinking properly, after enabling 'OEM Unlock' and rooting my phone, I decided to turn off 'OEM Unlock' (I figured this would be correct as on my old Nexus 7 I unlocked the bootloader, rooted & flashed it with a custom ROM and re-locked it no issues) but I didn't google anything to confirm this wouldn't cause issues. After rebooting, I realised my mistake: My phone would refuse to restart due to the FRP lock. Because of this, I flashed a new stock ROM from Sammmobile to fix this - from what I can tell this is a trusted website as everything linked back to there. This is where issues have started to occur: since flashing the stock ROM back, now when I unlock my phone for the first time a series of applications report they have crashed, notably:

LoggingService

Message Service

As well as occasionally:

Photos

Google Play Games

The issue I am now facing is that when I open the stock 'Messages' application, it crashes. Attempting to open it through settings to access the application settings, it crashes. I have since downloaded Google's 'Messenger' application and tried to use it, still no luck. I used Facebook's 'Messenger' application with integrated SMS, this just caused the recent messages screen to show 'An error occurred, please try again', however upon disabling SMS option I can see all my facebook messages.

So tl;dr:

- I cannot receive (or view - not sure. No notification was shown when an SMS was expected) text messages.
- Third party applications cannot view text messages in place of the default application.
- Message Service system application crashes when device starts

The following fixes have been tried:

- Clearing 'Messages' data and cache
- Clearing 'Message Service' cache
- Restarting the device (obviously)

Is anyone able to suggest other fixes to help solve my issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed. By running an [adb logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html) connection (adb logcat -f "storage/emulated/0/Logcat.txt") with my phone attached to my computer, I was able to log the output from the console when the application crashed. To produce the errors, I ran the Messages application. The output from the application can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/ZPgqnw6Y). To solve the issue, I navigated to the mmssms.db file (look [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16915/where-on-the-file-system-are-sms-messages-stored) for how to find it) and renamed the file to mmssms_old.db, essentially deleting it. I then rebooted the device and ran the application - it worked! Bear in mind all messages will be deleted, which is why I only renamed the database not deleted it entirely.