# Recover incoming SMS

Tags: rom-flashing, data-recovery

Accidentaly few weeks ago I make my phone bootloop. So to fix this I reinstall the ROM image (including recovery image and fastboot image). I realize that there are some of my important SMS haven't been backed up. So Is there any way to recovery the deleted SMS in my case? note: I already try to use Windows App like Coolmuster Lab.Fone for Android, dr.fone toolkit for Android, disklab_for_android but not helping at all.

Comment: SMS messages are stored in a system database file, if you performed a factory reset, which typically occurs as part of a factory image flash, they are not recoverable.

Answer (score -1):

It's not fool proof and you'll need to figure some parts on your own, but:

1. Create a backup of /data in recovery
2. Unpack the backup on your computer
3. Find your SMS app in restored /data/data. Most likely the app name is starting with `com.android.`.
4. Flash your new system image
5. Using adb, use `ls -l /data/data` to display permissions of the SMS app directory. Note the permissions.
6. Restore the SMS app directory using adb or Android file manager with root permissions
7. Change owner/group/permissions to be the same as you noted earlier.

Your SMS should be back at this point.

Comment: This would not restore any messages... The messages themselves are not part of the app, but are maintained in a system database. Restoring the app, or removing it, has no effect on the message store itself.

Comment: Good point: he then just needs to find the right file to restore -> https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16915/where-on-the-file-system-are-sms-messages-stored