# Can I transfer my sms messages from my old phone to my new phone WITHOUT using any third party software?

Tags: sync

The only answers I have been able to find want me to download third party software. It is NOT an acceptable solution to expose all of my SMS history to a third party. Maybe there's an open source solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## With root

If you're rooted or willing to root, you can check out this method: [Where on the file system are SMS messages stored?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16915/where-on-the-file-system-are-sms-messages-stored)

**Note:** If you're transferring between different versions of Android, or even ROMs, I would check if the SMS format is the same.

## Third party app

- There's **SMS Backup+**, which is an open source app I found - [GitHub](https://github.com/jberkel/sms-backup-plus), [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zegoggles.smssync).
- I'm using [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore) for a long time (maybe years) - from their [Privacy Policy](https://synctech.com.au/privacy-policy/), it seems that the only data they send is anonymous usage data to Google Analytics.

**Note:** You can use a well reviewed and popular third party app from play store (bonus if it's an editors choice), and after installing it (before even opening) - move to flight mode, backup locally, remove the app and transfer to your computer or other phone.

Comment: thanks, I didn't realize that sms backup+ was open source.